# WPF TextBox Inside ViewBox loses Cursor on resize

Tags: wpf, textbox, viewbox

I have a textbox inside a viewbox. When I try to resize the window, the textbox size and font size getting scaled, but if I try to focus the textbox and try move the cursor inside the textbox using keyboard, sometimes the cursor is getting disappeared. Is there a way to show the cursor always? Refer the below code which a TextBox inside ViewBox.

```
<Window x:Class="Resolution_Learning.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow">
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <Grid Width="2560" Height="1440" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Hello"/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Hello"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Hello"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Hello"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: At what exact key the textbox is loosing focus?

Comment: Try to shrink the window to small size and try to type in the textbox.

Comment: Works fine for me but the text is too small to see. Making the window bigger shows the text I typed while small. Strange ux imo, why not scrollbars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [BUG](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d3bc0cca-7b1f-436c-8f43-631c335559cd/textbox-caret-not-visible-when-scaled-down?forum=wpf) in **WPF**. I achieved this by creating my own style for `TextBox` `Caret`.

***XAML:*** ***`Style for TextBox`***

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="CaretStyle" >
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Canvas>                                    
                                <TextBox x:Name="Box" CaretBrush="Transparent"  Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox},Path=ActualWidth,Mode=OneWay}" 
                                          Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox},Path=ActualHeight,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <Border x:Name="Caret" 
                                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                                    Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Margin="0" Padding="0"
                                    Width="1"  Height="16"  Background="Black">                                        
                                    <Border.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard  x:Name="CaretStoryBoard" 
                                     RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                    Duration="0:0:0:1"
                                    FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames >
                                                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.750" 
                    Value="Transparent" />
                                                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.000" 
                    Value="Black"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>                                            
                                    </Border.Triggers>
                                </Border>
                            </Canvas>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="CustomTextBox_SelectionChanged"/>
                <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="CustomTextBox_GotFocus" />
                <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="CustomTextBox_LostFocus" />
            </Style>
```

***EVENTS:*** ***`For Caret Position`***

```
 void CustomTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Caret = FindChild<Border>(sender as DependencyObject, "Caret");
        Caret.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    void CustomTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Caret = FindChild<Border>(sender as DependencyObject, "Caret");
        Caret.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    void CustomTextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var CustomTextBox = FindChild<TextBox>(sender as DependencyObject, "Box");
        var caretLocation = CustomTextBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(CustomTextBox.CaretIndex).Location;
        var Caret = FindChild<Border>(sender as DependencyObject, "Caret");
        if (!double.IsInfinity(caretLocation.X))
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(Caret, caretLocation.X);
        }

        if (!double.IsInfinity(caretLocation.Y))
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(Caret, caretLocation.Y);
        }
    }
```

***Helper Method:*** ***`To Get Visual Child`***

```
     public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
   where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
            if (parent == null) return null;

            T foundChild = null;

            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                // If the child is not of the request child type child
                T childType = child as T;
                if (childType == null)
                {
                    // recursively drill down the tree
                    foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                    // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                    if (foundChild != null) break;
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                    // If the child's name is set for search
                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        // if the child's name is of the request name
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // child element found.
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return foundChild;
        }
```

> Just add above ***`Style`/`metods`*** in your code and set `Style` for
>   `TextBoxes` wherever you want and see the result. As I have created
>   this myself without any actual measurement of actual ***`Caret symbol`***, you may see a light shadow at some scale. please adjust
>   the look & feel as needed.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian yes..just did it...set CaretBrush="Transparent" in original textbox...I've updated in the answer..you can check... :)

Answer (score 1):

What I think happens here is this:

Since all the controls inside the *ViewBox* are re-sized, the caret is not always drawn due to pixel calculations.

To make it work, we will have to create our own caret. I've searched the web, in case someone already implemented this, and found [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633935/Customizing-the-Caret-of-a-WPF-TextBox) article by **d.moncada**.

I've downloaded the source code, and used the *CustomCaretTextBox* (instead of the regular *TextBox*) to test if it will solve the problem, and it did!

I strongly recommend you to try the solution, since it's looks elegant, works out of the box, and can be easily manipulated by your needs.

Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by making the style of TextBox Stretched as follows:

```
 <Style x:Name="TextBoxStyleTitle"
           TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                Value="Stretch"></Setter>
 </Style>
```