# Caret doesn't appear at some specific position of a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've read several differents post with this topics but each time, people have a problem of focus with their textbox (or color), but i'm not.

I've got this problem for 2 different C# WPF project in my company, 2 project very advanced and both have caret who disapear at some specific position. I can click with my mouse, if it's on a bad "caretIndex" it don't change anything, the caret don't appear.

For example, i have a textbox :

- I write "Q" => Carret appear
- I write "W" => Carret appear
- I write "E" => Carret doesn't appear, i can click with my mouse it
  don't change anything.
- I write "R" => Caret appear
- I write "T" => Caret appear

It s at some specific position but i can't know why. Some people had the same problem too ?

Thanks

Comment: this post may be able to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773364/wpf-textbox-inside-viewbox-loses-cursor-on-resize/36899669#36899669

Comment: did it help? or can you give your code?

Comment: yes it helps, but i didn't implement it because we have too much screen, so we kept the default caret, thanks for your answer

Comment: you can use that style for all screens by defining the style in app.xaml and as a base style for all textboxes. I mean too many screen is not really a problem if you are ok with that solution.